# Input com menos de três caracteres dispara função

Tags: javascript, funções, eventos

Estou realizando um exercicio de fixação que pede o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A contagem não esta dando certo, ele está pegando como se o número for maior que 3, por exemplo número 12, e não se tiver MAIS de 3 caracteres.

**Código:**

```js
function modificarAmarelo(){
      document.getElementById('mudar').style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
    }
    
    function perderFoco(){
      document.getElementById('mudar').style.backgroundColor = '';
      var caracteres = document.getElementById('mudar').value
      
      if (caracteres < 3){
        document.getElementById('mudar').style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000'
      } else{ 
        document.getElementById('mudar').style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00'
    }
    }
```

```html
    <input id="mudar" type="text" onfocus="modificarAmarelo()" onblur="perderFoco()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função perderFoco esta faltando pegar o tamanho da string para realizar o seu if

```
function perderFoco(){
  document.getElementById('mudar').style.backgroundColor = '';
  var caracteres = document.getElementById('mudar').value

  if (caracteres.length < 3){
    document.getElementById('mudar').style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000'
  } else{ 
    document.getElementById('mudar').style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00'
}
}
```

**Sintaxe em JavaScript:**
str.length

Answer (score 1):

Para obter os caracteres, você precisa adicionar o `.length` ao final do `.value`, que retornará a quantidade de caracteres em seu input, ficando assim:

```
var caracteres = document.getElementById('mudar').value.length;
```

Desta forma ele retornará um número inteiro, representando a contagem de caracteres e sua lógica dará certo.